# How to get resource usage report within tasks at specific level&

Tags: resource-planning, resources

Assume, I have following task structure:
`Project
  Stage 1
    Task1
    Task2
  Stage2
    Task3
    Task4`

I have resouces Res1 and Res2 assigned to tasks.

I need to know how much each resorce costs within every stage (not task). I can get view with this data on most detailed level, but I need to group it on other level.
So, I want to get:

```
Project
 Stage1
   Res1 cost1
   Res2 cost2
 Stage2
   Res1 cost3
   Res2 cost4
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is an elegant solution. My best (not very good) suggestion is that you duplicate the resources (e.g. "R1S1", "R1S2", "R2S1", "R2S2").
Then group the resources on a custom resource column (called "Stage") in your resource usage view.
Clumsy. Especially if you have a lot of resources.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a custom group for the Task Usage view.

**Group by**:
Field Name: Project
Field Type: Task
Order: Ascending

**They by**:
Field Name: Outline Number
Field Type: Task
Order: Ascending

**Then by**:
Field Name: Resource Names
Field Type: Assignment
Order: Ascending

**Note**: you'll have to check the box "Group assignments not tasks" to be able to group by Resource Names.

Add the Cost field and that should give you what you need.